# Do I need to repeat the pronoun "their" in my sentence, when describing something

Tags: pronunciation

I would like to describe the help and communication of some workers. I just wonder do I need to repeat the pronoun "their" in my sentence or not.

> I would like to thank the staff at the university A for their great and professional help and their respectful behavior.

or I must not repeat it as it is clear that I am still talking about the same people.

> I would like to thank the staff at the university A for their great and professional help and respectful behavior.

Comment: Either works in this case.  However, thanking someone for their "respectful behavior" could sound insulting.  It sounds like "respectful behavior" was not expected or took extra effort for them.  If you can be more specific about what you are thanking them for, we could offer different word choices.

Comment: It would be even okay to skip the first 'their' as well. Unless you mean thanking A for B's *something*, that 'their' is implied. ("I'd like to thank dr. Brown for the Dr White's spectrometer which Dr. Brown borrowed without permission and let me use." ;-)